# Password hashing in embedded systems

Tags: password-hashing

Are there good options for password hashing in embedded systems?  These systems often cannot afford slow hash functions.  I can think of a few approaches:

- Store the (hashed) passwords in a HSM that limits lookup rate.
- Generate high-entropy passwords, and do not let users choose their own passwords
- Use hardware password hashing
- Replace the password with RFID and a smartcard (probably a good choice anyway)

Comment: Why would you let an embedded device hash a password in the first place? You can do most of the work at the device accessing the embedded system. Codes, this one is for you :)

Comment: @MaartenBodewes because the password (or, more likely, passcode) is entered by a human at the system.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_access_module or indeed a smart card by the user (which would mean 2 factor authentication instead of 1 factor authentication, could be a good idea).

Comment: Perhaps secure offloading via Makwa's delegation feature.

Comment: @CodesInChaos what is that?

Comment: @Demetri It was an entry for the [password hashing competition developed by thomas pornin](http://www.bolet.org/makwa/). "Delegation is a way to enlist other systems for the bulk of the processing cost, but without trusting them. When delegation is possible, then higher work factors, hence higher security, can be used, by enlisting extra systems, e.g. rented cloud-based systems or even other connected clients."